# vba code for excel range on other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I try to use below VBA code to delete a range of data on other sheet, but it deleted data on sheet1 instead. Can someone help for this?

```
With Sheets("Found")
  lr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lr, 5)).Clear
End With
```

Thanks

Comment: Add a point like this `.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lr, 5)).Clear`

Answer (score 2):

Put a period.

```
With Sheets("Found")
  lr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lr, 5)).Clear
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much Davis and Lee! The code with period works.

Answer (score 1):

Minor typo when referring to your worksheet object.

On line 3, you didn't associate your Range with `Sheets("Found")` because you are missing the `.` in front of `Range(Cells(2, 1), cELLS(LR, 5)).Clear`.

Should look like this:

```
With Sheets("Found")
  lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lr, 5)).Clear
End With
```

Comment: You forgot associate the cells within the range definition as well.  `.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lr, 5))` will mean the `Range` on the `Found` sheet using the `Cells` on the currently active sheet (which will throw an error if they're different).  You'll need `.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lr, 5))`.  Also worth changing `Rows.Count` to `.Rows.Count` in case the active sheet is in Excel 2007+ (1048576 rows) and `Found` is in Excel 2003 (65536 rows) - again, the discrepancy will cause an error.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thank you!